# fitting a logarithmic model

Tags: r, regression, lm

I fit a linear model to my data using

```
lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 +  x7)
```

and I would now like to investigate whether a logarithmic model would fit the data better.

My predictors (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4`) have a minimum value of 0. Thus, I added a small constant (1e-10) to all entries which are 0 before trying to fit against the log of the x values using

```
lm(y ~ 1 + log(x1) + log(x2) + log(x3) + log(x4) +
     log(x5) + log(x6) + log(x7))
```

The model fit of the model with a linear relationship and the one with a logarithmic relationship are almost identical (AIC(linear) = -30357.95; AIC(log) = -30372.64), thus I think I am doing something wrong when fitting the logarithmic model.

```
lm(formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7)
Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max
-4.777e-04 -1.164e-04 -9.770e-06  1.026e-04  7.491e-04 

Coefficients:    
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    1.168e-03  5.974e-05  19.547  < 2e-16 ***
         x1    8.158e+01  5.637e+00  14.472  < 2e-16 ***
         x2   -1.304e-03  1.635e-04  -7.978 2.43e-15 ***
         x3   -5.176e-13  1.427e-13  -3.627 0.000293 ***
         x4   -6.124e-13  1.641e-13  -3.733 0.000195 ***
         x5   -6.611e-03  2.467e-03  -2.679 0.007434 ** 
         x6   -5.077e-03  1.055e-03  -4.810 1.62e-06 ***
         x7    2.183e-03  5.143e-04   4.246 2.28e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0001663 on 2077 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2026,    Adjusted R-squared:    0.2 
F-statistic: 75.41 on 7 and 2077 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Logarithmic model

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 1 + log(x1) + log(x2) + log(x3) +  log(x4) + log(x5) + log(x6) + log(x7))

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-4.173e-04 -1.174e-04 -1.583e-05  1.058e-04  7.471e-04 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)        
(Intercept)         2.097e-03  1.167e-04  17.962  < 2e-16 ***  
    log(x1)         9.849e-05  6.156e-06  16.000  < 2e-16 ***
    log(x2)        -4.416e-04  5.209e-05  -8.478  < 2e-16 ***
    log(x3)        -2.409e-05  4.244e-06  -5.677 1.57e-08 ***
    log(x4)        -7.947e-06  2.042e-06  -3.892 0.000102 ***
    log(x5)        -2.732e-06  5.078e-07  -5.379 8.34e-08 ***
    log(x6)        -5.071e-06  7.370e-07  -6.880 7.88e-12 ***
    log(x7)        -8.258e-07  4.449e-07  -1.856 0.063592 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0001658 on 2077 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2082,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2056 
F-statistic: 78.04 on 7 and 2077 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

[image: linear pairs plot]
[image: logarithmic pairs plot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Usually a well written R question uses reproducible example data to give an example of your data set with code that you've tried thusfar and any error messages you're struggling with. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  In this case at the very least please use reproducible data.

Comment: Are you taking the log of the dependent variable y? Also, is there a reason that you are setting the intercept to 1?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - Ah, my mistake. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 

@Anthony: No, I haven't taken the log of my dependent variable (in the examples, I have been working through people used logEstimate = lm(y ~ log(x))).

Comment: This is probably pretty basic but I am not even sure whether the way I am trying to fit a logarithmic model is correct (e.g. do I need to also take log(y) and is it okay to add a small constant only to all entries that are '0' or should I add the same constant to every entry?)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about this too much. In general, numbers are highly correlated with their logs:

```
set.seed(90)

y<-1:10
x1<-abs(rnorm(10))
x2<-1:10 + rnorm(10, 5, 5)
x3<-sample(10,10, replace= T) + 1:10
x4<-21:30*rnorm(1,5,1)+sin(1:10)
x5<-sample(100, 10, replace = F) * rpois(10,5)

mydata<-data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
mydata2<-log(mydata)

corr<-NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(mydata))
  corr[i]<-cor(mydata[,i],mydata2[,i])
corr

0.9516624 0.8498336 0.9343159 0.9703960 0.9989043 0.9540164
```

Which likely explains why your models are so similar.

A linear model seeks to find the coefficients for each variable that best describe the response. If you apply the same transformation to each explanatory variable, the model can still find such coefficients, though the coefficients should be different, which yours are. The fact that the log of the data is (likely) highly correlated with the actual data indicates that these models should be pretty similar.

Something you can try is to check out the model assumptions. Usually it is assumed that the residuals are normally distributed with mean 0 and fixed variance. You want to consider the residuals vs. fitted plots and the normal Q-Q plots. These can be accessed with `plot(model)` and `plot(model.log)` (or whatever you named the models) You want the residuals vs. fitted to look fairly random (any trends in this plot would indicate unequal variance and thus an inappropriate model). The Q-Q plot should be a straight diagonal line. Any unusual behavior with these plots might hint that something you did (or didn't do) was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My initial residuals are not normally distributed. Thus, I now applied scale() to every residual so that they all have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. Do I also need to standardise y?

Comment: I now applied `scale()` to every residual (e.g.`x1 = scale(x1)`) before fitting a linear model (`lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 +  x7)`) which worked fine. However, I am a bit lost regarding the log model. If I take the log of the standardised data (e.g.`x1 = log(scale(x1))`), then I am ending up with many `NaN`s. If I take the log of the initial data and apply `scale()` (e.g.`x1 = scale(log(x1))`), then I produce an error (`Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...): 0 (non-NA) cases`) when I am trying to fit `lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 +  x7)`.

Comment: You get the NaNs because the arguments of `log` just be greater than 0. You do not need to scale `y` so long as you remember to undo the transform you use (`log` in this case) when you make your predictions.